# Java - String to Fixed Byte

Tags: java, string, encoding, byte

I've searched a lot, and I can't seem to find anything related to converting a String to a fixed length byte in Java, I don't know if it's possible also, since we've got the encondings.

```
String word = "asdsda";
byte[] bytes = Java.Convert(word, 20);
```

As the example above shows just to examplify, is there a way in Java to convert a String to a fixed positive value of bytes?

Answer (score 1):

```
String word = "asdsda";
byte[] bytes = word.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Will give you 6 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I know that I can use the getBytes method with UTF-8 encoding, but I was wondering if there's a way of converting that string to a specified length byte, for example, convert that word into 16 byte array

Comment: Your comment does not parse.  First bytes are always the same length, 8-bits.  So presumably by "specified length byte" you mean "specified length byte array"?   First answer that, then we can proceed.

Comment: Ok, so then a given String of length X can be converted into an array of bytes of length Y where the value of Y depends on the encoding used.  For example, "Café" (with an accented e) is ALWAYS exactly 4 bytes when encoded as bytes in ASCII encoding (one byte per character) and 5 bytes when encoded using UTF-8 encoding.  There is no room for specifying length of the byte array, it is entirely determined by the string and character encoding given.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the thing is I'm working with IPv6 and UDP server/client, so for example, I have a byte array of 16 positions that represents the ipv6's machine destination. I know that I've already changed the topic, but if you have an idea of how can I convert the string I will be receiving representing the IPv6's machine destination from the user to a 16 byte array using the encondings that Java has, please answer me.

Comment: IPv6 addresses are usually encoded as hexadecimal numbers (base 16).  So, you could think of a given IPv6 address as 128 characters (0-1) in base 2, or 32 characters (0-F) in base 16.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipv6  Search stackoverflow for java+hexadecimal, there are lots of examples of converting bytes to hex and back.

Comment: Thanks dude, I'm not so sure if I understand, I have to convert the string address to bytes using the getBytes method and then to hex? is that it? Anyway I will try looking for hexadecimal converting methods, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

character encoding is a rule, the character to byte conversion, you must at some encoding rules under the constraint, otherwise it is pointless